# Datediff in sql query using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this c# code, in it a query which i want to display in a datagridview:

```
   string select = "SELECT E.employeeNumber AS 'Employee Number',
    E.employeePrivateName +' '+E.employeeFamilyName AS 'Employee_Name',
    DATEDIFF (MONTH,E.startWorkingDate, GETDATE()) AS 'Seniority in
    Month'
    FROM TblEmployee E " ;
       Connection c = new Connection();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c.con); //c.con is the      connection string
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

The problem is with `datediff`, as due to that the query results I'm presenting in a datagridview comes up empty.

Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you run this query on sql management studio editor?

Comment: `DATEDIFF` will give you an integer number (not a date object or anything similar). Do you really want to name the first column `'Employee Number'` (with a blank)?

Comment: Please show the code used to load the DataGridView

Comment: What do you mean? How do you want the query in C#? LINQ? SqlCommand?EF?

Comment: How is this question related to C# at all? Does the query work as expected in SSMS, otherwise it is a sql question only and the C# tag is just misleading.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ,the question is all about c#, i updated the code in the question, have a look

Comment: @user2023203: I see that you're really using C#. However, you haven't told us why you are sure that the reason for your issue(which is not clear)  can be found in the C# code and not in the query. So does the query work in SQL-Server management studio?

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter.  The question is about the SQL query, not the C# code.

Comment: In sql server 2008 the query works perfectly, when I drop the datediif all together, the datagridview is populated with the query, but when using the datediff I get a blank datagridview

Comment: I'm guessing E.startWorkingDate is not a "time, date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2, or datetimeoffset value".

Comment: debug check ds.Tables[0], does it have value?